# Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'bSegue''

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, storyboard

In the storyboard from the UITableView added one segue named bSegue and bSegue Identifier class name is abcViewController.

In the code writing it as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case PDF: 

        viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bSegue"];
        break;
            default: 
        viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
} 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

but when tried to run app it shows error **NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'bSegue'**

I double checked it segue identifier is correct then why it is giving this error.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing view controller identifiers with segue identifiers.

Your line `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bSegue"]`
is looking in the storyboard for a view controller with a `Storyboard ID` of `bSegue`.

What you want to do is call the segue identifier you have created with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

so it would look like `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bSegue" sender:nil];`